# Profile Manager: Enroll gives a error 500

Tags: osx-server, ssl, profile-manager

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to configure a server to use it as a MDM solution via Profile Manager.

So far I have:

- Configured my OS X Server.
- Added a signed SSL certificate.
- Sent some invitations to end users.

BUT when the user reaches the **https://mock_domain/mydevices/** and tries to enroll it (does a POST to **https://mock_domain/devicemanagement/mdm/mdm_enroll) returns a **error 500**.

After checking the **error_log** it looks like there is some security issues (probably related to the SSL certificate):

*AH01630: client denied by server configuration*

I dont know exactly what is happening but might be related to the SSL certificate.

My OpenDirectory service is configured with a self-signed certificate and the rest of services are configured to use the certificate that I bought.

I have tried to change the certificate of the OpenDirectory to explore that path but I can't and I dont know if it is really related to the error 500 issue.

Any advice??

Comment: The messages is : The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but it seems to be resolved through opening Server, turning Off open directory, waiting a few seconds, then turning it back On. Repeat if necessary.

This has happened twice in the past month, both times were resolved by doing this. I'm now searching as to why this occurs, and if it happens again I'll test reinstalling the Server App.

Hopefully this helps someone.